# Eclipse R.java changes not saved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

When I "quick fix"an error like "gcm_unregistered cannot be resolved or is not a field" and click "Create constant gcm_unregistered in type String" there is a add in R.java ->

public static final class string {

```
    public static final int gcm_unregistered = 0;
```

After saving that the project rebuild and creates a new standard R. java without the added line.
I have seen examples with more lines in R.java so something in my project is going wrong or I missed a setting?

Comment: That should work, until your build process is overwriting the `R.java` in some way

Comment: I thought so. Can't find a setting NOT to overwrite... Do you?

Comment: Harry : I dint know `R.java` is a system file (I thought it as a general java file and gave suggestion) . PS : I have close to no idea about `android development` my comment was totally based on my knowledge of java alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what gcm_unregistered is supposed to be but I recommend Not editing the R class because its generated. If you'd like to add something to the Resources (R) do it through the xml. Heres Android's Site for manipulating/accessing resources http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

EDIT: So you want to add a string resource then go to the strings.xml under res/values/ and add gcm_unregistered with the value you want.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! When adding a string in stings.xml is appears in R.java...

Comment: @Harry When you try to get it in your app, you'll first have to get it as a String, and then parse it into an integer. It's just a little extra processing, but it is avoidable.

Answer (score 3):

`R.java` is a file automatically generated by the Android Build process. Any changes you make to it will be lost when the project is built again.

If you want to add your own constants, just make yourself a `Constants` class (I usually call mine `C`, to keep it short)

```
public class Constants {

    public static final int gcm_unregistered = 0;

}
```

Now you can just access it as `Constants.gcm_unregistered`.

**A deeper explanation of R.java**

Android considers XML-based layouts to be resources, and as such layout files are stored
in the res/layout directory inside your Android project. Strings, colors, raw binary data like sound files etc. are also considered resources. Essentially, anything legally allowed in any of the `/res` folders is a resource.

When you run the Android build system, the `aapt` tool generates a new `R.java` file and overwrites the old one. This file will contain pointers to all your `IDs`, `Strings`, `Layouts`, `Colors` etc. `R.java` should never be modified manually. If you want a value in `R.java`, you should check if you can legally add it to one of the `/res` folders, and if you can, do so. However, AFAIK, you cannot have `int` values added to it (Note that while everything thing in `R.java` is an `int`, they point to various other resources. So while `R.layout.mylayout` will be an `int` value, it actually tells Android to use the `mylayout.xml` file.

There is an excellent writeup on R.java and different parts of the /res folder over [here](http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2883).

Comment: I liked your answer a lot better than mine not sure about the Constants class though for this particular problem but definitely a nice answer +1

Comment: The good thing about the constants class is that you can put other stuff in it. It'll eliminate the chance of typos in sharedprefs etc. if you store the filename and key values as constants. This answer was just one example. And thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

R.java gets modified by the build, and you are not supposed to modify it as your changes will be lost.

Comment: Why does the "quick fix" gives this solution?

Comment: Quick fixes are suggestions. Programmers shouldn't rely solely on suggestions by the IDE.

Comment: Quick fix is a Eclipse feature, which doesn't know that R.java in a Android project will get modified by the android build.